# Error when type float, no error when type double

Tags: java, floating-point, double

I wrote a simple java program that outputs what your weight would be on the moon. The following code

```
    class MoonWeight
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            double earthWeight = 195.0;
            double moonWeight = earthWeight*.17;
            System.out.println("On Earth you weigh " + earthWeight +
            ", on the moon you weigh " + moonWeight);
        }
    }
```

Produces the output "On Earth you weigh 195.0, on the moon you weigh 33.150000000000006", but when I use type `float`:

```
    class MoonWeight
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            float earthWeight = 195.0;
            float moonWeight = earthWeight*.17;
            System.out.println("On Earth you weigh " + earthWeight +
            ", on the moon you weigh " + moonWeight);
        }
    }
```

I get the following error `error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float`, why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To specify that a number is a float is must end with an F or f so the code would read:

```
float earthWeight = 195.0f;
float moonWeight = earthWeight * .17f;
```

Answer (score 1):

this works

```
    float earthWeight = 195.0f;
    float moonWeight = earthWeight*0.17f;
```

see on javadocs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

```
Data Type   Default Value (for fields)
float       0.0f
```

i.e. every float needs an "f" at the end

Answer (score 1):

0.17 is double, therefore operation with double returns double, in your example this one `earthWeight*.17` returns double and you try it to save into float.

To fix it, you have to use float, which is really easy : `earthWeight*.17f`.

It is similar as if you want to save long into int, you cant do that imlicitly as it cant be done, if that long is too big. Same principle is for double and float.

Answer (score 0):

This is because float is less precise than double. If you convert a number from double to float you can lose information. The compiler tells you about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It shows you error because decimal literals in java are implicitly double. If you want to use them as a float you have to put letter F/f at the end of your number.

For example: `float earthWeight = 195.0F;`